# Autoload de controllers usando namespace

Tags: php, namespace, php-autoload

Estou tentando dar uma reestruturada em um microframework pessoal, antes não usava muito padrão na estrutura do projeto, agora joguei todo meu back-end na pasta `source`, e estou usando `namespaces` para separar o código. Estou com problema ao fazer o `autoload`, quero dar um `new Crontrolador()` sem antes ter que usar o `use \Controllers\Controlador`.

Nunca entendi direito essa parte então por isso vim pedir ajuda, atualmente na minha classe **Core** tenho o seguinte método que é responsável por fazer algumas validações e chamar o controlador:

```
private function addControllerAndModel($class, $method, $page = false)
{
    $class = ucfirst($class);
    $controller = "{$class}Controller";

    if(file_exists(__DIR__."/../../Controllers/{$controller}.php")) {

        echo "Controller existe<br>";
        if($page)
            $this->importRels(Relationships::get('*'));

        $this->importRels(Relationships::get($class));

        $instance = new $controller();

        if($page) {
            if(count($_POST)) {
                if($_POST['token'] === Session::get('token') or in_array($_POST['token'], Settings::get('allowsAjax'))) {
                    Session::set('token', false);
                    Saved::create();
                    $method = "{$method}Posted";
                }
                else {
                    Errors::display('Token inválido', DOMAIN);
                    exit();
                }

            }
            else {
                if(!Session::get('token'))
                    Session::set('token', md5(crypt(time(), '$1$rasmusle$')));
                $method = "{$method}Deed";
            }
        }


            $instance->{$method}();
       // else
            //Errors::display("Método não encontrado [{$controller}/{$method}]");
    }
    //else
        //Errors::display("Controlador não encontrado [{$controller}]");

    echo $this->controller . " / " . $this->method;
}
```

Resumidamente, eu vejo se existe o arquivo do controlador requisitado, caso exista eu importo os Models relacionados àquele controlador, e em seguida instancio o controlador, após isso tenho alguns controles de segurança, e por fim chamo o método desejado.

Atualmente da erro na linha 126 (`$instance = new $controller();`):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HomeController' not found in
>   /home/leonardo/www/tcc/newframework/source/Kernel/Kernel/Core.php:126

Segue a estrutura de pastas do meu projeto:

Project

```
--binary
--public
----js
----css
----librarys
----views
--source
----Controllers
------MeuControlador.php
----Kernel
------Kernel
--------Core.php
----Models
------MeuModel.php
--settings
--third
--trials
```

A função citada está presente no Core.php, e os controladores ficam dois níveis atrás e na pasta Controllers. Não entendo como fazer tal autoloader com namespaces, logo a única tentativa que tenho é esse método acima.

Um exemplo de controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: leonardo
 * Date: 17/09/16
 * Time: 14:52
 */

namespace Controllers;

class HomeController extends Kernel\Control\Controller
{
    public function startDeed()
    {
        echo "Hello World!!";
    }

}
```

É possível dar `new HomeController()` sem declarar `use Controllers\HomeController`? Tentei usando:

```
$instance = \Controllers\{$controller}();
```

Mas não funcionou :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é como você está instanciado sua classe.

Não misture a declaração do objeto com *strings*, pois não vai funcionar.

Ao invés disso, concatene o nome do classe com o *namespace* esperado numa *string*:

```
<?php

namespace Legumes {

    class Batata {

    }

}

// volta para o namespace global
namespace {
    $classe = 'Batata';

    // Cuidado especial com a barra invertida, ela é utilizada como escape
    $fqn = "\\Legumes\\{$classe}";

    $instance = new $fqn;

    var_dump($instance);
}
```

Veja [rodando](https://3v4l.org/Q4uU3).

Comment: Funcionou, não sei como fui deixar esse detalhe simples kk